# WP Oembed not passing through the “autoplay=1” variable

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, youtube, oembed

I'm having this problem.

I am passing this through a custom field [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E6P1Q-UycHA&autoplay=1)

`(notice the "autoplay=1")`

But when I load the video on my theme using `wp_oembed_get`... it displays the video fine, but it does not listen to the `autoplay=1` variable I am passing through.

I need the videos to play on the load of the page.

Comment: That was a very helpful comment! ...

Comment: Have you found a solution ? i'm also trying to pass this value in my php script.

Comment: ^^ No, I had to end up passing it through a custom field

Answer (score 6):

I think the way to do it is using wordpress filters:

```
function modify_youtube_embed_url($html) {
    return str_replace("?feature=oembed", "?feature=oembed&autoplay=1", $html);
}
add_filter('oembed_result', 'modify_youtube_embed_url');
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution in functions.php

```
function embed_responsive_autoplay($code){
    if(strpos($code, 'youtu.be') !== false || strpos($code, 'youtube.com') !== false){
        $return = preg_replace('@embed/([^"&]*)@', 'embed/$1&showinfo=0&autoplay=1', $code);
        return '<div class="embed-container">' . $return . '</div>';
    }
    return '<div class="embed-container">' . $code . '</div>';
}

add_filter( 'embed_oembed_html', 'embed_responsive_autoplay');
add_filter( 'video_embed_html', 'embed_responsive_autoplay' ); // Jetpack
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

look up function wp_oembed_get and use the args to pass the autoplay... should work fine. Just paste in the url of the video not the &autoplay... you'll code that into the args part of the function.

Answer (score 0):

So, after some research on this, the best way to do this is to leverage the `oembed_fetch_url` filter hook to add extra arguments to the oEmbed request URL. My specific goal was to allow an autoplay paramater, but this method is built to be easy to tailor to any oEmbed argument you need.

First, add this to your `functions.php`:

```php
<?php
/**
 * Add parameters to embed
 * @src https://foxland.fi/adding-parameters-to-wordpress-oembed/
 * @src https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/ec417a34a7ce0d10a998b7eb6d50d7ba6291d94d/wp-includes/class-oembed.php#L553
 */
$allowed_args = ['autoplay'];

function koa_oembed_args($provider, $url, $args) {
    global $allowed_args;

    $filtered_args = array_filter(
        $args,
        function ($key) use ($allowed_args) {
            return in_array($key, $allowed_args);
        },
        ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY
    );

    foreach ($filtered_args as $key => $value) {
        $provider = add_query_arg($key, $value, $provider);
    }

    return $provider;
}

add_filter('oembed_fetch_url', 'koa_oembed_args', 10, 3);
```

This function takes the generated oEmbed URL and its corresponding arguments and checks it agains a hard-coded list of whitelisted arguments, in this case `['autoplay']`. If it sees any of these whitelisted keywords in the arguments passed to the oEmbed filter, it adds them with their given value to the oEmbed URL.

Then, all you need to do is add the oEmbed parameter to your shortcode in the Wordpress editor, like this:

```
[embed autoplay="true"]https://vimeo.com/1234567890/1234567890[/embed]
```

Be aware that the oEmbed class in WP uses the postmeta as a cache for these requests, so if you've embedded the target URL before, you might have to clear your postmeta cache in some way or add a cache buster of some kind to the target URL. If the link is in the cache, the filter hook will never get to run.

I hope this makes sense, as I feel like it's a pretty useful feature that's surprisingly hard to figure out how to achieve.

Answer (score -3):

This can be easily fixed by modifying the wp_oembed_get() function in wp-includes/media.php to this:

```
function wp_oembed_get( $url, $args = '' ) {
    // Manually build the IFRAME embed with the related videos option disabled and autoplay turned on
    if(preg_match("/youtube.com\/watch\?v=([^&]+)/i", $url, $aMatch)){
        return '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/' . $aMatch[1] . '?rel=0&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
    }

    require_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-oembed.php' );
    $oembed = _wp_oembed_get_object();
    return $oembed->get_html( $url, $args );
}
```

Comment: Also, be sure to run the following SQL query after you make this change so that the embed is refreshed:

DELETE FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key LIKE '_oembed_%'